# How can I find the sw-context-token while registering using js?

Tags: react-native, shopware

how can I find the sw-context-token while registering using js?

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Please _do_ provide some context for the code - is this a code sample you've copied from somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I have copied it from shopware documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the registration request, you can leave the `sw-context-token` header empty.

In the response, you'll be provided with the `sw-context-token` header which you have to use for later requests that require this header to be set.

For further reference see the documentation:

- API endpoint:
  https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/store-api/b3A6ODI2NTY1Ng-register-a-customer
- "Register a customer" guide: https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/store-api/ZG9jOjExMDc4MTU2-registering-a-customer